# How to set up Eclipse's Build Configurations to produce a proper, debuggable NDK app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, adt

We have an Android NDK project that has three different build configurations:

1. DEBUG - armeabi
2. DEBUG - armeabi-v7a
3. RELEASE - aremabi + armeabi-v7a

We specify separate aremabi and armeabi-v7 debug configurations due to a known bug in the Android loader, where if more than one EABI is specified, the debugger may launch the wrong EABI version of the App and no native breakpoints will ever hit ([More details here, at the end of the document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493043/Why-your-Android-NDK-breakpoints-might-fail-and-ho)).

On the past, we edited the `Application.mk` file and specified the desired EABI by means of the `APP_ABI` variable.

We would like to avoid this manual editing and take advantage of Eclipse's Build Configurations and choose the proper EABI setting automatically.

So far, we have a working solution by adding conditionals to the `Application.mk` file

Here is how our `Application.mk`  looks:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_CONFIG),RELEASE)
    APP_OPTIM := release
    APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
else ifeq ($(BUILD_CONFIG),ARMEABIV7A_DEBUG) 
    APP_OPTIM := debug
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
else ifeq ($(BUILD_CONFIG),ARMEABI_DEBUG)
    APP_OPTIM := debug
    APP_ABI := armeabi
endif
```

Additionally, we customised the compiler build command line in Eclipse so that the proper `BUILD_CONFIG` variable is passed to the make script.

This works very well for compilation purposes, but the problem begins when we try to debug the application. The thing is that we don't know how to pass the `BUILD_CONFIG` variable to the `ndk-gdb` script.

Running the `ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI` command will always return `ARMEABI` (expected since we are not explicitly defining the `BUILD_CONFIG` parameter), and as far as I understand, this is the value that `ndk-gdb` is reading in order to decide which version of the application will be launched by the debugger.

Has anyone managed to get this working or have an alternative solution where we can get compilation and debugging working properly with Eclipse's Build Configurations?  Running a command that patches or renames the `Application.mk` file is a possibility, but we don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 5):

Android 4.0 has bug. If you provide `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` code then `armeabi` code is loaded even if you have ARMv7 compatible CPU. Android 4.0 ignores `armeabi-v7a` when `armeabi` is available.

That is why you can create 2 versions of your lib targeted to `armeabi` (ARMv5)

But there is no ARMv5 CPUs (HTC Hero)
So most CPUs are ARMv6 or ARMv7

You should detect your CPU in Java and load proper native lib.
Doing these will give you control what .so loaded exactly.
You would be able to create lib with NEON support.

Comment: Thank you very much Artem for your response.  Indeed, we have added proper steps to control that run-time bug you describe.  What we're looking for is actually a compile-time solution that allows us to select the type of build (debug or release) and the eabi specification (ARM or ARMV-v7) without requiring us to manually edit the .mk files. We would rather select a configuration build and have everything working automagically, including integrated debugging. I'll try to analyze the ndk-gdb script to see if I can change the parsing logic that determines the current APP_ABI setting. Cheers!